# Для чего нужны динамические Proxy классы?

Tags: java, proxy

После прочтения множества информации про прокси классы и как они создаются не нашел для себя элементарного "ответа и примера", а для чего это вообще нужно? 
зачем нам приводить прокси к определенным интерфейсам, если в любом случае сколько интерфейсов не наследовал бы класс, в нем не могут определяется одинаковые методы. Значит мы можем спокойно использовать класс в котором определенным методы разных интерефейсов и использовать их просто создавая обычный инстанс класса. 
Вопрос: зачем нужны эти динамические прокси и какой реальный пример есть на практике если же мы просто можем использовать обычный инстанс класса для вызовов тех самых методов.

Answer (score 2):

Могу привести такой пример.

```
interface Account {
    public void withdraw(double amt);
}

Account acc = RestClient.create("http://example.com/", Account.class);
acc.withdraw(5);
```

Т.е. есть один раз написали клиента (RestClient), и штампуй себе интерфейсы под разные рест сервисы. Очень удобно.

Comment: не очень то я понял этот пример, но спасибо)